# How to dynamically change bookmarklet parameters using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bookmarklet

I have an angular single page app. I'm trying to create a bookmarklet but want the bookmarklet to reference a different JS file depending on if I'm in prod or local development environment. Here's roughly the raw bookmarklet:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){var jsCode = document.createElement('script');
jsCode.setAttribute('src', 'http://mydomain.com/scripts/bookmarklet.js');
document.body.appendChild(jsCode);})();">My Bookmarklet</a>
```

This works just fine and will load up the bookmarklet.js. However in Angular, I'm setting a scope variable that is the root to either the prod domain or local host like this in the controller:

```
$scope.rootUrl = prod ? 'http://mydomain.com/' : 'localhost:3000/';
```

Then on the angular page I'm doing:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){var jsCode = document.createElement('script');
jsCode.setAttribute('src', '{{rootUrl}}/scripts/bookmarklet.js');
document.body.appendChild(jsCode);})();">My Bookmarklet</a>
```

For some reason, when the angular variable is added to the bookmarklet, chrome prepends an '**unsafe:**' like this when it renders and makes the bookmarklet useless.:

```
<a href="unsafe:javascript:(function(){var jsCode = document.createElement('script');
jsCode.setAttribute('src', 'http://mydomain.com/scripts/bookmarklet.js');
document.body.appendChild(jsCode);})();">My Bookmarklet</a>
```

I've searched around and can't seem to find a solution or understand why this is happening. Any help towards solving this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Safety, organization, and testability are three core aims of the angular framework. As such, it will NOT allow you to set javascript as the href of an `<a>` tag by default -- it is generally considered sloppy and unsafe, can be easily exploitable, and is very difficult to test.

The framework provides the ng-click directive to execute javascript in response to a click event, which replaces the need for `<a href="javascript:whatever">` in ALMOST all cases, and to enforce safety, the angular compiler will by default ONLY allow `mailto:`, `ftp:`, `http:`, and `https:` in an href.

This means that if you need an unsafe javascript href that can be dragged to the bookmarks toolbar, you must configure the angular compiler in a config block like so:

```
angular.module('moduleName').config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {   
  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|javascript):/);
}]);
```

(**Note**: Older versions of angular (< 1.2) use $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist)